# What is the difference between C.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 locales?

Tags: python, linux, docker, debian, locale

I'm migrating a Python application from an Ubuntu server with a `en_US.UTF-8` locale to a new Debian server which comes with `C.UTF-8` already set by default. I'm trying to understand if there could be any impact from this change.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In general `C` is for computer, `en_US` is for people in US who speak English (and other people who want the same behaviour).

The *for computer* means that the strings are sometime more standardized (but still in English), so an output of a program could be read from another program. With `en_US`, strings could be improved, alphabetic order could be improved (maybe by new rules of Chicago rules of style, etc.). So more user-friendly, but possibly less stable. Note: locales are not just for translation of strings, but also for collation (alphabetic order, numbers (e.g. thousand separator), currency (I think it is safe to predict that $ and 2 decimal digits will remain), months, day of weeks, etc.

In your case, it is just the UTF-8 version of both locales.

In general it should not matter. I usually prefer en_US.UTF-8, but usually it doesn't matter, and in your case (server app), it should only change log and error messages (if you use `locale.setlocale()`.  You should handle client locales inside your app. Programs that read from other programs should set `C` before opening the pipe, so it should not really matter.

As you see, probably it doesn't matter.  You may also use `POSIX` locale, also define in Debian. You get the list of installed locales with `locale -a`.

Note: Micro-optimization will prescribe `C`/`C.UTF-8` locale: no translation of files (`gettext`), and simple rules on collation and number formatting, but this should visible only on server side.

Answer (score 28):

Here are some reasons why I added `LC_TIME=C.UTF-8` in `/etc/default/locale`, in case it helps someone:

It provides a 24-hour clock instead of AM/PM in Firefox for HTML5 input type=time (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) and uses a datepicker in the format DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY for HTML5 input type=date (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

It allows to use YYYY-MM-DD international date format (ISO 8601) with a 24-hour clock when replying to emails in Thunberbird.

Previously, it was possible with `LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8` (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Date_display_format) but there is a bug currently and it stopped working (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907#c155).

Edit: Now even the `LC_TIME=C.UTF-8` workaround does not work for Thunberbird (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426907#c197) but at least `en_IE.UTF-8` provides the European date format DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY.

Answer (score 7):

There might be some impact as they differ in sorting orders, upper-lower case relationships, collation orders, thousands separators, default currency symbol and more.

C.utf8 = POSIX standards-compliant default locale. Only strict ASCII characters are valid, extended to allow the basic use of UTF-8

en_US.utf8 = American English UTF-8 locale.

Though I'm not sure about the specific effect you might encounter, but I believe you can set the locale and encoding inside your application if needed.

Comment: I want to upvote this, but I haven't yet simply because I don't know if it is true... However, I will note that it at least makes sense. It would be great if a reference could be included in this answer.

Comment: What is "basic use of UTF-8"?

Comment: Especially: Only strict ASCII in C.utf-8 vs. allow the basic use of UTF-8? Wasn't it the goal of multibyte encodings to leave ASCII behind? If C.utf-8 really is ASCII only, it would explain my current problem and why I came here...

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm there is effect on different locales (C.UTF8 vs en_US.UTF8). I recently deployed one python program into a new  server, and it performed differently. The old and new servers are both Ubuntu 18 servers, and the only difference is the locale (C.UTF8 vs en_US.UTF8).  After setting the locale in new server as C.UTF8, they behave the same now.

It is easy to set the locale for a single application in Linux environment. You just need to add `export LANG=C.UTF8;` before your application. Assume you execute you application as `python myprogram.py`, then you type:

`export LANG=C.UTF8; python myprogram.py`

Comment: Thanks Ben Lin, could you also share what were the differences you noticed?

Comment: Hi Marcelo, sorry I can't pin point the differences, because my product line is too long. It is related to ocr/python/numpy/opencv and some more.

Comment: When you ask "what is the difference between X and Y" and someone answers "yes, there is a difference" it's a bit frustrating.