# What might cause "commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)" when using pandoc as a library?

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I'm using pandoc as a library, and the relevant code snippet is:

```
module Lib
    ( latexDirToTex, latexToTxt
    ) where

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import           Data.List (isSuffixOf)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import           ForeignLib (chdir)
import           Path
import           System.Directory (getDirectoryContents )
import           Text.Pandoc
import           Text.Pandoc.UTF8 (toText)

latexToTxt :: Path b File -> IO T.Text
latexToTxt  fPath = do
  fileBS <- BS.readFile $ toFilePath fPath
  result <- runIO $ do
    doc <- readLaTeX def $ toText fileBS
    writePlain def doc
  handleError result
```

From this, you can see that I'm basically just calling `readLaTeX` to read in a LaTeX document.

However, when I try to run this code, I have lots of trouble in practice, with errors like the one in the title:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
       &  & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 15 & 15 &  &  \\
  \hline
      0 & \vline & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vline & 1 \\
      1 & \vline & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vline & 3 \\
      2 & \vline & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vline & 9 \\
      3 & \vline & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vline & 26 \\
      4 & \vline & 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vline & 72 \\
      5 & \vline & 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1 & 0 & \vline & 191 \\
      6 & \vline & 0 & 6 & 15 & 20 & 15 & 6 & 1 & \vline & 482 \\
      7 & \vline & 0 & 0 & 21 & 35 & 35 & 21 & 7 & \vline & 1134 \\
      8 & \vline & 0 & 0 & 0 & 56 & 70 & 56 & 28 & \vline & 2422 \\
      9 & \vline & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 126 & 126 & 34 & \vline & 4536 \\
      10 & \vline & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 252 & 210 & \vline & 6930 \\
      11 & \vline & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 462 & \vline & 6930
    \end{array}', rendering as TeX:
      0 & \vline & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
          ^
  unexpected "\\"
  expecting "&", "\\\\", white space or "\\end"
arxiv-pandoc-static: <stdout>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

Contrasting this to using the pandoc executable directly, no such errors occur and I receive quite good output. I'd like to configure the pandoc readers to be as flexible as possible and to not bail out on errors (or better yet, avoid the errors in the first place). How can I achieve this through the pandoc API?

Comment: After thinking about this again, I realized I may need to look into what `handleError` is doing (which seems to immediately exit with an error message: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.10.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Error.html#v:handleError).

Comment: `stack test` recently gave me this message. The problem was actually a type error, but for some reason it thought `commitAndReleaseBuffer ... invalid char` was a more informative error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that this is less of a pandoc issue and more one of a GHC or the *text* package. The answer can be found in a completely unrelated Haskell project, the [hledger docs](https://github.com/simonmichael/hledger/blob/0751536d255cddc80513283f57f6c8f9f85f85d5/hledger/hledger.info):

> **Getting errors like "Illegal byte sequence" or "Invalid or
> incomplete multibyte or wide character" or "commitAndReleaseBuffer:
> invalid argument (invalid character)"**
>
> Programs compiled with GHC (hledger, haskell build tools, etc.)  need to
> have a UTF-8-aware locale configured in the environment, otherwise they
> will fail with these kinds of errors when they encounter non-ascii
> characters.
>
> To fix it, set the LANG environment variable to some locale which
> supports UTF-8.  The locale you choose must be installed on your system.

So running something like `export LANG=C.UTF-8` in your shell should resolve this.

Comment: That certainly seemed to fix the issue, though it has me wondering how the `pandoc` executable managed to avoid the issue. Perhaps I'll get around to looking into it, and will post back if I find out.

Comment: After looking at the source, it appears the main `pandoc` executable gets around this by running other processes behind the scenes, and does this same trick by setting `LANG` as above, although I'll note pandoc uses the slightly different `en_US.UTF-8`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673886/what-is-the-difference-between-c-utf-8-and-en-us-utf-8-locales for notes on differences between these.

Comment: I'll note that `C.UTF-8` appeared to give better results in my case (otherwise it failed as before).